# Data Source For Images (Soil Sealing, Water Bodies, Surface Flooding, Parks etc.), at Scale of 1:30000

Tags: data-request, images, open-source, remote-sensing

I want image data sources for following conditions:

Mapping soil sealing and water bodies at scale of 1:30000

Mapping surface flooding when there is persistent high cloud cover

Mapping parks in urban areas and the sub-classes: lawn, trees, tree groups, water bodies, road (sealed) and road (unsealed) at a scale of 1:3000.

What are the individual best RS data sources for above conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel 2 and Sentinel 1 would be my answer.
For water bodies sentinel 1 is the best shout.
Land classification would be sentinel 2

Both datasets can be downloaded from [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus/#/home).